# Why doesn't this give me the factorial?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, factorial

```
function FirstFactorial(num) { 
      for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
           return num * i; 
      }        
    };

  console.log(FirstFactorial(8))
```

I just want to know what writing my code like this doesn't print the factorial? Instead I only get 56, which is 8 * 7. I thought that if i use the for loop that it would keep going?

Comment: You're aborting the for loop with your return statement. You need to return outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    return num * i; 
}
```

It will return `num*(num-1)` value. Since it will return the value in the first iteration.

Instead use:

Using recursion:

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
    if(num==1)
        return num;
    else
        return num*(FirstFactorial(num-1))
}
```

or:

```
fact=num;
for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    fact*=i; 
}
return fact;
```

---

EDIT: On demand of OP to explain how the return would work in the recursion method.

Regarding Recursion:

```
return num*FirstFactorial(num-1)
```

actually first multiplies `num` with the return value of `FirstFactorial(num-1)` which would be `(n-1)!`. Hence what actually will happen is:

1. `FirstFactorial(num-1)` is called. (FirstFactorial function is called with parameter `num-1`.
2. The return value of `FirstFactorial(num-1)` which is `(num-1)!` is multiplied with the value of `num` to get `num!`.
3. This value (`num!`) is then returned by the function `FirstFactorial()` when passed with parameter `num` or `FirstFactorial(num)`

Now on calling `FirstFactorial(num-1)` inside the `FirstFactorial(num)`, FirstFactorial function will again be executed checking the first if condition. If it fails, it will return the value of `(n-1)*FirstFactorial(num-1 - 1)`. This will recurse until first if condition is satisfied and value is returned without calling the `FirstFactorial` again.

You can also think the function as:

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
    if(num==1)
        return num;
    else {
        a = FirstFactorial(num-1);
        a = a * num;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, this may sound stupid, but for the return statement in the recursion, why does it have to have FirstFactorial in the: return num*(FirstFactorial(num-1))? What I'm trying to ask is what does multiplying it by FirstFactorial(num - 1) do that is different from multiplying it simply by (num - 1)?

Comment: @joyfulchute Well `n! = n*(n-1)!` Hence you need to use `return num*FirstFactorial(num-1)`. What you said was something like `n! = n*(n-1)`. I hope you understand now the need of `FirstFactorial(num-1)` and not `n-1`. If you still have doubt, do ask.

Comment: Thanks! Although I don't fully grasp the idea, I think I'm starting to understand it more now! I think I'm just confused as I don't see how I can multiply by Firstfactorial(num - 1), because as I see it, for instance, when I call FirstFactorial(8), the code runes (8 * FirstFactorial(7))?

Comment: @joyfulchute it is the return statement that is giving meaning to `num*FirstFactorial(num-1)`.  On returning a value, FirstFactorial will return the value of `(num-1)!` which is then multiplied by `num` to get `num!`. It is the return value of `FirstFactorial(num-1)` that you are multiplying with `num`.

Comment: so by returning num * FirstFactorial(num - 1), FirstFactorial(num - 1) becomes (num-1)! ? If it's not too much trouble, would it be possible for you to walk me through what exactly happens when the return statement executes and what happens to FirstFactorial(num - 1)?

Comment: @joyfulchute I have edited my answer. Hope it helps you in understanding. If you still can't understand, feel free to ask again and again.

Comment: you have been a very big help to me! I'm starting to understand some more of it, but I guess what's really bugging me right now is that don't get why the returning n * FirstFactorial(num - 1) gives (num)!, instead of just num *  (num - 1). Does the if statement have something to do with it?

Comment: @joyfulchute let's assume that `FirstFactorial(a)` returns the value of `a!`. Then finding `(a+1)!` is like `a! * (a+1) == (a+1)!` or `FirstFactorial(a) * (a+1) == (a+1)!`, that is `FirstFactorial(a+1)`. Hence our assumption of assuming that `FirstFactorial(a)` returns `a!` is correct.

Regarding why `n*FirstFactorial(num-1)` gives `num!` and not `num*(num-1)` is because `FirstFactorial` function returns the factorial of number that is passed to it as parameter. Hence `FirstFactorial(n-1)` is equivalent to `(num-1)!` and not `(num-1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand how this code works now!

Answer (score 1):

When you use return, it escape the function and returns the first `num*i`, to prevent it, make a local variable in your function and return that at the end of loop.

**Example:**

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
    var result=1;
    for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        result *= i; 
    }        
    return result
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 8 and multiplying 8*7 and return 56. You are not accumulating. You need some recursion here:

```
function FirstFactorial(num)
{
    if (num == 1)
        return num;
    else
        return num * FirstFactorial(num - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function FirstFactorial(num) { 
  var fact = 1;
  for(var i = num; i > 0; i--) {
       fact = fact * i; //here you are returning on your first iteration iteslef and hence issue
  }
  return fact;        
};

console.log(FirstFactorial(8))
```

when you say `return`, it would abort the method call and return to the parent with the value (if it does) that you return. So in your case, it will return 8 * 7 = 56

Answer (score 0):

You return your value at the first time you iterate in your loop, instead of at the end. This should do the trick:

```
function FirstFactorial(num) { 
      var result = num;
      for(var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
           result = result * i; 
      }
      return result;        
    };

  console.log(FirstFactorial(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is iterating once because has a return, you should storage  in a variable and return after te loop iterates.

```
function factorial(num) {
    var result = num;

    for (var i = num - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        result = result * i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note factorial is a candidate to be recursive:

```
function factorial(num) {

    if (num > 0) {
        return num * factorial(num - 1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```